# Smallest size of message in gRPC

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I need to find out what is the average size of request in gRPC when Im sending a string to server and receiving a string from server?

I read somewhere it should be around 20 Bytes but what I see in Network Monitor app is that the request is above 500 Bytes. So is it the smallest possible size of a gRPC message size or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single `rpc`, gRPC needs to do a few things:

1. Establish HTTP/2
2. *(Optional)* Establish TLS
3. Exchange headers for the RPCs (size depends on schema)
4. Exchange actual RPC messages (size depends on schema)
5. Close connection

gRPC is meant to be used for *many RPCs on a single connection* so the smallest possible `rpc` message is really the bytes used for 4.

**[Edit]**

I checked and the minimum data exchanged for an `rpc` **is over 500 bytes**, in terms of raw IP packets.

I used the gRPC `helloworld.proto`, changed to send an `int32`.

Inspecting packets in Wireshark showed the following IP packet totals:

- 1286 bytes to establish connection, exchange headers and do the first `rpc`
- 564 bytes for each subsequent `rpc`
- 176 bytes for client `Shutdown`

Of those 546 "minimum" bytes:

- 67% was TCP/IP overhead (acknowledgements, packet headers)
- 10% was "trailer" data sent after the `rpc`

Comment: Im sending a single string to the server and getting single string response from server, what is the maximum size do you think it takes? When I make request to server and get response I track the request size and response size and request size is always 500~ Bytes. This is breaking my expectations with gRPC significantly.